# Created objects do not save in database

Tags: ruby, activerecord

What did I do:

1. create a new ruby app `rails new campaigns_manager`
2. move to **campaigns_manager** directory, generate first scaffold **campaigns** 
   `rails generate scaffold campaign name:string` and migrate
3. add root route `root to: 'campaigns#index', as: 'campaigns'`

Such a few strings of code. Then I start server to test it. Everything looks and works ok, but when I try to add a new campaign, nothing saves. After pressing "Create campaign" button I receive in console something like that:

```
Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-25 22:30:40 +0300
Processing by CampaignsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sKom3YBDEbOcqbSt3gLGWPqBNeqkEw6M59hlwrmH4tM=", "campaign"=>{"name"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Create Campaign"}
  Campaign Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" 
  Rendered campaigns/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 35.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

then I redirect to campaigns list and there is no new campaign. Table **campaigns** in **db\development.sqlite3** is empty.
Furthermore, I add **print** methods to campaigns controller to check if I call correct methods. And I see, that **create** method is not called when I press "Create campaign" button.
My **campaigns/new** view:

```
<h1>New campaign</h1>

<%= form_for(@campaign) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', campaigns_path %>
```

Why cannot I save my campaigns to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `routes.rb` file.

```
root to: 'campaigns#index', as: 'campaigns'
```

The alias `as: 'campaigns'` tries to consume all requests. There is no need to add an alias to your root directive, it already has one by default: `as: 'root'`

Your `routes.rb` file has to look something like this:

```
resources :campaigns
root to: 'campaigns#index'
```

More on Routes in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, I became smarter)

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the view code in `campaigns/new`, but clearly the form there is posting to `/`, which you can see from the log, is being handled by the `index` action (which is as it should be according to your routes). You have to make sure your form in `campaigns/new` is posting to `/campaigns` (which in Rails RESTful routing resolves to the `create` action). If you're using `form_for` (which I think is what the scaffold generates), it should look something like this:

```rb
<%= form_for @campaign do |f| %>
```